# Golang Swagger annotation for enum input parameter

Tags: rest, go, swagger, go-swagger

I am not sure how to specify annotation for an input string parameter for a rest call. Where input parameter can take one of three possible string values.

If I have to assume there will be a drop down menu with these three value (containers/bundles/web) and the user will chose one of them. Previously I am referring to this [documentation](https://goswagger.io/use/spec/params.html)  to create annotation for an in parameters.

I am trying to annotate go code, so that I can generate `swagger.yaml`  automatically (`swagger generate spec -o ./swagger.yaml --scan-models`). Unfortunately, I couldn't find an annotated example that expects enums or the input parameters is limited to certain values. Looks for some code examples.

Comment: Are you trying to annotate your Go code to produce a Swagger specification? Or are you trying to generate a server from a Swagger specification?

Comment: @MicahParks I am trying to annotate go code, so that I can generate ```swagger.yaml ``` automatically (```swagger generate spec -o ./swagger.yaml --scan-models```)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some thing like this with enum annotation should work.

```
// swagger:parameters artifactInfo
type ArtifactTypeParam struct {
    // The type of artifact
    // in: path
    // enum: container,bundle,executbale
    // required: true
    ArtifactType string `json:"artifactType"`
}
```